# synchronizing sqlite3 to external db in django

Tags: django

folks, i am building trying to build an app that stores its data on sqlite3 and then synchronizes it to the maybe postgres in the cloud, i have tried django-synchro, it seeems quite outdated, i had to make several changes to it before it could work with Django 2.0 , I now face this issue `AttributeError: 'ManyToManyField' object has no attribute 'rel'`
 and the code related to it is `def get_intermediary(models):
    res = {}
    for model in models:
        res.update((m2m.rel.through, _get_remote_field(m2m)) for m2m in model._meta.many_to_many
                   if not m2m.rel.through._meta.auto_created)`

is there a way i can get around this or maybe a django package that can help with synchronizing with two databases .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `.rel` attribute has been replaced with `.remote_field`. This was deprecated in Django 1.9, and finally removed in 2.0. See [this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/1.9/#field-rel-changes) of the release notes.

Comment: `.to` has been replaced with `.model`. Accessing that property emits a deprecation warning: `Usage of ForeignObjectRel.to attribute has been deprecated. Use the model attribute instead.`